# Robot Framework - Browser doesn't remember quantity in shopping cart

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

Robot Framework - Browser doesn't remember quantity in shopping cart.

I wrote robot script by open browser and pick a item then I close browser and open it again but the shopping cart show quantity as 0

**My robot code:**

```
Test Shopping card
   [Tags]   Test
   Open Browser   ${BROWSER}   Chrome
   Maximize Browser Window
   Add item to cart     &{item}[P16]
   Input Text   &{cart}[quantity]   2
   Textfield Should Contain    &{cart}[quantity]   2
   Close Browser
   Open Browser   ${BROWSER}   Chrome
   Maximize Browser Window
   Element Should Contain    ${SHOPPING_CART}   2
```

**Expected Result:** System should show quantity in cart as 2.

**Actual Result:**
Element `'xpath=/html/body/header/div[2]/div[3]/a/span'` should have contained text `'2'` but its text was `'0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On creating a new browser (`Open Browser`), it starts off with a clean/new profile - with no cookies or local storage from previous sessions.
As your cart content is (as obvious by your intent) stored in them, they are lost the moment you close your browser.

The current flow is the same as if you are manually opening  a browser, adding an item to the cart, then opening a new browser in incognito mode - and expecting to see the item in the cart. Or me opening a browser to the same site, and seeing your item in my cart :)

If you want to verify the cart is preserved on navigation, you could change the steps to

1. Open the browser to your site
2. Add an item to the cart
3. Navigate to another page - `Go To    https://www.google.com`
4. Go back to your site
5. Verify the item is still in the cart

Thus you will verify the cart is preserved in a session.

If you want to verify it's also kept across sessions, you have to start the browser with specific profile, and make sure cookies are stored in it. You'll also have to take special steps the site's cart cookies are not present (they are cleaned/wiped) in the initial step of the test (step 1), but are preserved on the second page landing (step 4).

Comment: Thank you for your idea. @Todor Minakov